# Rails getting the value of a field not included as a attribute the object in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, controller, jquery-select2

I have a rails form to update company information it calls on the update action, I have a field that I want to get the value of as a parameter on submit, the field is not included as a attribute of company, so the value is currently not coming in as a parameter.  Is it possible to get the value of this field?  I am using the select2 gem in the field that I need to get the value from.  The field is below.

```
<div id="allStations">
  <select multiple id="list-markets" style="width:350px">
    <% Market.all.each do |market| %>
      <option value="<%= market.id%>"><%= market.name%></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit a value from a field that is not an attribute on the object, then you can use a `FormTagHelper`.  These are the helpers that end in `_tag`.  You might want to try something like:

```
<div id="allStations">
  <%= select_tag "list-markets", options_from_collection_for_select(Store.all, :id, :name), style: "width: 350px", multiple: true %>
</div>
```